# Exception non gérée à 0x100e3cf2 dans shervinemami.exe : 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv

Help me how to sove it, [an alert window when t try to execut my code][1]

Noting that debugging is fine and successful but when try to execute the code, I get a message in the output window; Exception non gérée à 0x100e3cf2 dans shervinemami.exe : 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero..which means that there is an exception of a dision by zero, this is the code:

```
        IplImage* LOULILI::cropFace(IplImage*image, CvPoint eye_left, CvPoint eye_right,double offset_pct[2], CvSize dest_sz)
          {
      //calculate offsets in original image
            double offset_h = offset_pct[0]* dest_sz.width;
            double offset_v = offset_pct[1]*dest_sz.height;
           //get the direction
           double   eye_directionX,eye_directionY;
           eye_directionX= double(eye_right.x - eye_left.x);
            eye_directionY=double(eye_right.y - eye_left.y);
          // calc rotation angle in radians
          double rotation;
          rotation =  double(-atan2(eye_directionY,eye_directionX )*180/PI);
           // distance between them
            double dist = distancePoints(eye_left, eye_right);
             //calculate the reference eye-width
             double reference = dest_sz.width - 2.0*offset_h;
           //scale factor
              double scale = dist/reference;
          //rotation par rapport à l'oeil gauche
         //matrice de rotation
      cv::Mat affine_matrix;
       affine_matrix =cv::getRotationMatrix2D( eye_left, rotation, scale );
           //mtx est la conversion de image IplImage* en matrice mtx
            cv::Mat mtx=cv::Mat(image,true); 
          cv::Mat mtx2;
         cv::warpAffine(mtx, mtx2, affine_matrix,mtx.size(),cv::INTER_LINEAR,                                cv::BORDER_CONSTANT,cv::Scalar::all(255));
  //mtx est la conversion de matrice mtx2 en  image IplImage* 
  //IplImage* image1 =&mtx2.operator IplImage();
 IplImage image1 =mtx2;
 IplImage* im22=(IplImage*)&image1;
      //crop the rotated image
         double crop_x =double(eye_left.x) - scale*offset_h;
       double crop_y =double(eye_left.y) - scale*offset_v;

 double crop_size0 = (double)dest_sz.width*scale;
  double crop_size1= (double)  dest_sz.height*scale;
         CvRect region;
       region.x=cvRound(crop_x);
       region.y=cvRound(crop_y);
        region.width=cvRound (crop_size0);
         region.height=cvRound(crop_size1);

            IplImage* im44=cropImage(im22,region);
          //crop((int(crop_xy[0]), int(crop_xy[1]), int(crop_xy[0]+crop_size[0]),                       int(crop_xy[1]+crop_size[1])))

          IplImage* image3=resizeImage(im44, dest_sz.width, dest_sz.width);
           return im44;
                  }
```

Comment: So, in the code you posted there is only one division operation `dist/reference` -- I guess I'd start there...

Comment: Visual Studio will show you what line the error is on... You are dividing by zero somewhere, so just see what line the error is on and make sure you don't divide by zero!

Comment: Yep, same conclusion as jedwards here - based on what you've shown us, I'd be checking that PI was properly defined as a constant.

Comment: #define PI 3.14159265 all is fine only when i execute the code there is the problem.the execution crashed

Answer (score 0):

There is no integer division in that code, so there's no way we can help. You might want to compile in debug mode and set the debugger to break on C++ Exceptions (you can do this in the Exception window in Visual Studio).